# Import Error For Sklearn mean_sqaured_error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, import, modulenotfounderror

I am getting an import error for the `mean_squared_error` module. The error message reads `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mean_squarred_error'`.

Original Code *(which produced error)*:

```py
from sklearn import metrics

import mean_squarred_error

mean_sqaured_error(predictions["actual"], predictions["prediction"] )
```

I then tried rewriting the code as follows:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squarred_error

mean_sqaured_error(predictions["actual"], predictions["prediction"] )
```

However, I am still getting the same error. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Only one `r`: `mean_squarred_error` -> `mean_squared_error`

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the spelling error i have it as one r in the code.

Comment: And you still have this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have some typos:

```
#                             HERE --v
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squarred_error

#      v-- HERE
mean_sqaured_error(predictions["actual"], predictions["prediction"])
```

Do:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error(predictions["actual"], predictions["prediction"])
```